# @Bean doesn't get injected when I use Optional type and run SpringJUnit4ClassRunner Test

Tags: java, spring, junit

When I run SpringJUnit4ClassRunner Test in Spring, I @Autowired values from @Bean.

But the problem is we are using multiple Configures to set the @Bean like the following

```
@Configuration
public class ParentConfig {
    @Bean
    public Optional<Integer> sampleOptionalInteger(@Value("${sample.int:}") final Integer sample) {
        return Optional.of(sample);
    }
}
```

And the child configure which uses the parentConfig is

```
@Profile("sample")
@Import({
        ParentConfig.class,
})
@Configuration
public class ChildConfig {
    @Bean
    public Integer sampleInt(final Optional<Integer> sampleOptionalInteger) {
        return sampleOptionalInteger.map(s -> s).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("You need to specify sample int"));
    }
}
```

The test code is

```
@ActiveProfiles("sample")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        ChildConfig.class,
})
@TestPropertySource(locations = {
        "sample.properties"
})
public class SampleConfigTest {
    @Autowired
    private Integer sampleInt;
}
```

When I debug execute the test code, in `ParentConfig`'s argument `sampleOptionalInteger`, we can get the integer from propeties (can confirm by pausing at breakpoint).
But we can't get the value in `ChildConfig`'s argument, `sampleInt`, and it turns out to be `Optional.empty`.

I have no idea why this happen.  Can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: Can you share your `application.yml`. I suspect it's the colon after `sample.int:` that's causing the problem. Try changing it to `@Value("${sample.int}"`

Comment: application.yml

sample.int=10

and, I've tried  `@Value("${sample.int}")`, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: And, I also tried to '@Bean(name="hoge")' to identify the @Bean